# how to fix old gradle version?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I imported an old project from github to use it in a course, then I received this error message :

Support for builds using Gradle versions older than 2.6 was removed in tooling API version 5.0. You are currently using Gradle version 2.2.1. You should upgrade your Gradle build to use Gradle 2.6 or later.

Comment: You will just need to upgrade the version.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to update your versions to these:

/project/build.gradle
`classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"`

/project/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip`